# codeigniter php Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: user_id

Tags: codeigniter

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(15) { 
        ["guest_list_id"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["event_type_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["event_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["guest_attendance_status"]=> NULL 
        ["user_id"]=> string(1) "9" },
```

When accessing `$user['user_id']` , I get the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: user_id

Code from Comment

```
if (!empty($user)) { 
   foreach ($user as $key => $value) { 
      $user_details = array(
         'user_id' => $user['0']['user_id'],
          'eventTitle' => $user['pre_wedding_event_title']
       ); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: `$user` is an array, so you should rather use `$user['0']['user_id']`

Comment: works but doesn't solve my problem. I am a little confused, i have many of those arrays and i am trying to loop through, code: if (!empty($user))
        {            
            foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
                $user_details = array('user_id' => $user['0']['user_id'], 'eventTitle' => $user['pre_wedding_event_title']);
                              
            }
            
        }

Comment: Instead of `foreach ($user as $key => $value)`, do something like `foreach ($user as $usr)` and you'll be able to get your values doing something like `$usr['user_id']`.

Comment: $user['0']['user_id'], this should be $value['user_id']

Comment: thanks BrianRay and devpro . works fine.